# Google Sheet Query output for difference in succesive values in a date column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet holding dates(mm/dd/yyyy) in a column. I want to calculate the difference between two successive values(input sheet) in the date column and return the output to a seperate sheet (summary sheet) when there is a difference of more than 1. Trying to use google sheet query since it has the property of executing a query result and automatically add rows based on the retrieval. The first sheet(input) is mostly a dataentry sheet where dates are being entered as an when a process is progressed. So whenever two consequtive date entries differ by more than 1, I want to report the start_date(i.e date value in ith row) and the end_date(i.e., date value i+1th) row. For each i and i+1 th row to be a new row in the summary sheet agaist column start_date(ith value) and end_date(i+1th value). Is there any way we can achieve this is google sheets?

Updated with some reference data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-PAwtw07LxH8OYJ9wvPdivcoLHjz1IRHBrqOieqixY8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I have updated the question with an example sheet.

Comment: The main point here is that the summary sheet to automatically add new rows when there is a new entry in the dataentry sheet which matches the date difference criteria. Dragging the summary sheet to calculate the result for newer rows in the dataentry sheet may not be the greatest option. That's why usage of google query would be a preferable choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to do the subtraction outside the query (because Query doesn't allow arithmetic on dates) like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({{A2:A},{A3:A;""},{A3:A;""}-{A2:A}},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3>1 label Col1 'Start Date',Col2 'End Date'"))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

You probably ought to check for any empty cells between dates, so you could add another condition to the Where clause:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({{A2:A},{A3:A;""},{A3:A;""}-{A2:A}},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3>1 and Col1 is not null label Col1 'Start Date',Col2 'End Date'"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and confirm. Don't have much ideas on complex google sheet calculations. That's why for help here.

Comment: sorry for comming late, It worked, thanks. However, can you explain the formula? A more specific question is, does { } defines the dataset query shall perform, and what is the meaning of ; in the curly braces? Also why do we need to wrap it in ArrayFormula() function? @Tom

Comment: I believe Tom's formula is providing 3 columns for the query - Col1 is all the dates in column A, Col2 is all the dates in column B except for the first (with a blank cell added for the last row, to make the columns the same length) and Col3 is the difference between the dates in Col1 and Col2.  When this is greater thn 1, the dates are more than one day apart, and satisfy the WHERE criteria.  The ";" element is to add two ranges one above each other, ie. in the same column.  So {A3:A;" "} adds a space (or cell) below the range A3:A, to make the range the same length as the range A2:A.

Comment: @Arunavo, I believe that the ARRAYFORMULA is required to enable the subtraction operation,  ```{A3:A;""}-{A2:A}```, to be performed, which is caluclating the values for Col3.  Otherwise, an array minus an array results in an error.  Someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes - @kirkg is absolutely correct. The only thing to add, perhaps, is that I had to use the inner curly brackets to get the ranges with the added cell {A3:A;""} to parse correctly. If there was any possibility of empty rows between dates, you would get a spurious output, so I will add a check to my answer.